# Inserting image into GUI button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to create a button with text in it as you can see in the code comments. Yet I am unsure as to why when I try to add an image it doesn't accept it. I thought it may be since I am using a CustomGUISkin that may override it?  But I am not sure on that. Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong or is their a simpler way?
I'm using Unity and c# as my script language.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PracticeButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUISkin CustomGuiSkin;

    private float x; 
    private float y; 
    private float z; 
    private float p;

    // here
    GUIContent content = new GUIContent();
    public Texture2D image;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        x = 0.5f * Screen.width;
        y = 0.625f * Screen.height;
        z = 0.5f * Screen.width;
        p = 0.125f * Screen.height;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnGUI () {

        GUI.skin = CustomGuiSkin;

        // here
        GUI.skin.button.normal.background = (Texture2D)content.image;

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(x, y, z, p), content, CustomGuiSkin.button )){ // replace content with "this" and this will show
            Application.LoadLevel("PracticeScene");
            DeathOnImpact.dead = false;
            Score.myScore = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `Texture2D` variable `image` set from anywhere else in code?

Comment: No, not that I know of this would be this first time using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the image as content/label this may help

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIContent-image.html

If you want as an style remove this line `GUI.skin.button.normal.background = (Texture2D)content.image;` and the `public Texture2D image;` and create a custo style or change button default style from your custom skin on inspector/editor.

If you create your button style as custom style in your CustomGuiSkin you need to change this `CustomGuiSkin.button` by a string with your custom style name like `"myButtonStyle"`.

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(x, y, z, p), content, "myButtonStyle" )){ 
    // content
}
```

If you change standard button style from your CustomGuiSkin just ommit the style from your button declaration, it will get by default once you had set your current skin as your CustomGuiSkin already.

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(x, y, z, p), content )){ 
    // content
}
```

You can find more information about using GUISkins on documentation:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html

Comment: The removal of content, CustomGuiSkin.button to if(GUI.Button(new Rect(x, y, z, p), new GUIContent(icon))){ worked perfectly. Thanks